# Error al compilar proyecto de xamarin en windows 10

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Tengo un proyecto de **Xamarin** el cual en Mac se compila bien pero en Windows me aparecen los siguientes errores:

> error APT0000: Attribute "statusBarBackground" already defined with incompatible format.
>
> error APT0000: Original attribute defined here.
>
> error APT0000: Attribute "layout_anchorGravity" already defined with incompatible format.
>
> error APT0000: Original attribute defined here.
>
> error APT0000: Attribute "layout_insetEdge" already defined with incompatible format.
>
> error APT0000: Original attribute defined here.
>
> error APT0000: Attribute "layout_dodgeInsetEdges" already defined with incompatible format.
>
> error APT0000: Original attribute defined here.
>
> error APT0000: Color types not allowed (at 'statusBarBackground' with value '#000000').

He intentado cambiar la versión del *monoandroid* a la 9 en el *csproj* pero no funciona, también intente migrar el *package config* a *package references* pero desafortunadamente tampoco funciono.

Comment: Te puede servir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622202/aapt-attribute-layout-anchorgravity-already-defined-with-incompatible-format?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: lo estas abriendo con visual 2019?

Comment: Lo abro con visual studio 2017